# In the red-underlined sentence, is it semantically proper if I change “the” into “this”?

Tags: grammar

In the red-underlined sentence, is it semantically proper if I change “the” into “this”?

I’ve checked on Cambridge Dictionary that there are three common collocations of “sense”: *in a sense*, *in every sense*, and *in no sense*. But *in this sense* can also be seen in newspapers published by BBC and the Guardian, so I believe, it is grammatically right.

However, I scant tell if it is semantically right in this context.

Hope your sagacious answer can walk me through it.

Thanks in advance![image][image]

Comment: Do not post photographs of pages. Type the text you are asking about.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is associated with the whole context, which is too voluminous to be type out. Luckily, my question was already solved by dear Mr.Roseman. Thanks for your attention, of course.

Comment: All you needed was "Poetry gave them words to attach to their feelings. They enjoyed folk ballads too. In **the** sense, music and poetry joined hands. Should I change 'the' to 'this'?"

Answer (score -1):

"In this sense" is perfectly idiomatic. However it would not be the right choice here. It is used when summarising what has gone previously; but this sentence is not doing that, it is introducing a new thought. The correct choice here would be "In **a** sense".

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr. Roseman! I got your point, simple and clear!